# How to pronounce paths of links/URLs properly?

Tags: pronunciation

I have been watching Linus Tech Tips for a while now and am confused about their pronunciation of links/URLs. When they make an advertisement, they vary between two different pronunciations. Let me show you using the example of `foo.com/bar`:

1. foo dot com slash bar
2. foo dot com forward(s) slash bar

*I am not sure whether they say it with or without s since it always melts with the s of the slash*

My question now is: Is there a difference between these pronunciations or do they both mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: There's no *s* -- it's "forward slash": "/", as opposed to a "backslash": "\". HTH.

Comment: If I type such an address using ***backslashes***, my Brave browser (Chrome clone) silently switches them to ***forward slashes*** anyway, so it's pretty much irrelevant whether I'm told *and make the distinction* between ***forward*** and ***back*** here. But as a Brit, I'm quite happy to assume the (optional) trailing ***s*** in ***forwards slash*** (which I'll sometimes articulate myself, with no particular guiding principle as regards when I do it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your browser might do that, but it's not necessarily something that other browsers should or actually do.

Comment: Related (duplicate?) - [Forward vs Forwards](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/forward-vs-forwards)

Comment: @CJ Dennis : Those are just technical details. Plus so far as I'm aware, all URL's take the same form regardless of language, so such details aren't specifically relevant to ***English***. To my mind, the only thing that *might* be relevant is the status of that optional ***s*** in ***forwards slash*** (which Webster taught Americans was a "corruption", but Brits never took that on board).